# beforeAll is not executed in test using forEach loop

Tags: node.js, jestjs

The following code does not execute any test

```
let testCases = [];
beforeAll(async () => {
  input = {description:"x", queryStatement:"", expectedStatusCode:200,assertStatement:""}
  testCases.push(input);
});

testCases.forEach(({ description, queryStatement, expectedStatusCode, assertStatement}) => {
  describe(`GraphQL > query: ${description} with query ${queryStatement}`, () => {
    it(`should return status code ${expectedStatusCode}`, async () => {
      const token = await fetchData(username, password);
      // Encode credentials
      const response = await axios.post('https://xxx.foo.com/graphql', {query: queryStatement}, { 
      headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.access_token}`}
      });
      expect(response.status).toBe(expectedStatusCode);
      //console.log(response.data);
      eval(assertStatement);
  });
});
```

});

I expected to execute the `beforeAll` to fill the list of `testCases`, but nothing happened.

Comment: Use describe.each

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks a lot for the tip :) But what if those tabular style of input is stored in a csv file, then how to read?

Comment: Test suites are supposed to be declared before tests run. The use of beforeAll is not justified. It's unclear why it's async. testCases.push(input) could be at top level of test module. If there are other concerns, please, list them

Comment: `beforeAll` runs before test _execution_, which is necessarily after test _discovery_. Purely on a JS control flow basis it should be obvious that `testCases` is empty when iterated over.